# JavaFX 2 WebView: How to enhance the scrollbars

Tags: java, webkit, javafx-2

I have implemented a Log-Viewer using the JavaFX WebView.

However there is one big issue for the users of that Log-Viewer: the scrollbars of the webviewer are very thin. I even had an issue (on Windows 7 / XP, strangely not on Windows 8) that when clicking on the scroll slider, it "hopped" away and it is not always easy to catch that slider and sometimes the scrolling does not work.

It took me some effort and research and I found that I can change the scrollbars with CSS. However I had some issues that either the automatic scrolling did not work any more or I had some "smear" effects and the scrollbar was not painted correctly.

Maybe someone has found another solution for the problem - I will present my solution below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution uses CSS to change the webkit scrollbar. See
[CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/examples/WebKitScrollbars/)
for an introduction.

There are some points to be considered:

First:
When using `position: absolute;` the scrolling in javascript - like `window.scrollTo` will not work any more.

Second:
The `background-color` attribute for the `scrollbar-track` is mandatory. When left out (and not using absolute positioning) the redraw functionality of the scrollbar does not work any more. This seems to be a bug in the webkit.

```
    body {
        /* hide the horizontal scrollbar */
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    /* make the scrollbar a little wider */
    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 16px;
    }
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track  {
        background-color: white;
    }
    /* the slider or "thumb" has some rounded edges and a shadow and it's a little translucent */
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        border-radius: 6px;
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
        background: rgba(159,216,239,0.8);
    }
    /* I don't like the scrollbar to be so tiny on large documents - hence I set a minimum height */
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical {
        min-height: 100px;
    }
    /* Use a more translucent slider when the window is inactive */
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
        background: rgba(159,216,239,0.2); 
    }
```

When using this CSS in the `<style>` tag in the content of the HTML used by the `WebEngine` the scrollbars are new shiny glossy blue and wider scrollbars.
This also solves the issue of the "hopping away" of the scrollbar on Win7/XP.

To change the Horizontal scrollbar as well - the height attribute in `webkit-scrollbar` has to be provided and the `min-width` attribute in `...-scrollbar-thumb:vertical` can be provided along.

Comment: Hey Michael! Which part of this CSS was fixing the part described as " it is not always easy to catch that slider and sometimes the scrolling does not work"?

Comment: Seems they fixed the "hop-away" issue in recent JavaFX or I couldn't reproduce it. However the scrollbars are still quite small by default and I don't think they look good, so I go on using the CSS solution.

Comment: I figured it out myself that the issue is gone if you style your scrollbar with webkit CSS. I think that under the hood JavaFx switches from custom rendering to user-defined stylesheet and that gets rid of the issue.

Comment: Michael, could you please post the line that applies that css to the WebView? I tried the following with some combinations - does not work: `webView.getStylesheets().add("package/styles.css")`