# JavaFX Webview: scrollbar is overlapping content

Tags: java, css, javafx, webview

When using JavaFX Webview, the scrolling bars overlap the content, potentially hiding controls and the likes.

I tested in JavaFX 11, 13, 14, and 15 early access, and all have the same issue.

How do I make it so the scrollbars don't block content?

Here is a short tidbit:

```java
package com.company;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        WebView webView = new WebView();
        webView.getEngine().load("https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/modals/basic/");

        VBox vBox = new VBox(webView);
        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox, 960, 600);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Webview: [image]Chrome: [image]Firefox: [image]Edge: [image]

Comment: No issue with jdk1.8.0_171

Answer (score 1):

I recommend getting **ScenicView** - it's a great tool. It's helped me a lot with similar issues.

The `ScrollBar` is part of the `WebView`. In order to change its behavior, you need to create a custom `.css` just for the `WebView` engine.

Then apply said style using:

`webView.getEngine().setUserStyleSheetLocation(getClass().getResource("/path/to/style.css").toExternalForm());`.

**hotzst**, mentions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32847059/customize-javafx-webview-scrollbar-width#) a link to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32751342/javafx-webengine-overwriting-a-websites-stylesheet-with-local-files) and overall explains that the behavior of the `ScrollBar` is dependent on the web page. You can alter it by introducing it's own style (via a local `.css` file) - but it can also damage the structure of the said page.

**michael_s**, provides some interesting tips and links [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15418628/javafx-2-webview-how-to-enhance-the-scrollbars/15418654) that you might want to check out by modifying the `webkit` used for it.

Unfortunately I'm not that experienced with it, so I don't know what exactly needs to be modified.

Hope this helps a bit at least.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comment! However, I don't know if the link answers my question -  I don't want to hide the scrollbar, I just want it to stop overlapping content.

Comment: @GuillaumeF. I've edited my answer. Not with a solution, unfortunately, but with at least a bit more relevant information to your question. Also, I recommend adding `CSS` to your question's tags.